# Python signxml - Sign an XML document with just public/private keys

Tags: python, xml, django, public-key-encryption

I'm working on a django port of a asp.net app that generates and signs an xml document using just a public key/private key pair.

I've managed to duplicate every aspect of the xml generation except for the signature aspect.  I've found the signxml library that seems like it would allow me to do this, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. Here's the code I've got (modeled after the example [here](https://signxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#synopsis)):

```
# store keys as strings
cert = open(signprivatepath).read()
key = open(signpublicpath).read()

data = ET.fromstring(docstring)
xmldsig_stuff = xmldsig(data, 'sha1')
signed_root = xmldsig_stuff.sign(
    key=key,
    cert=cert,
    algorithm='rsa-sha1',
    c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'
    )
verified_data = xmldsig(signed_root).verify()
return verified_data
```

signprivatepath and signpublicpath are both paths to PEM formatted keys.

When I run the code, it returns the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/site/245/download-site-license

Django Version: 1.9.5
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['licenses.apps.LicensesConfig',
 'simple_history',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\projects\django\swlicensing\licenses\views\site.py" in downloadSiteLicense
  206.         signedXMLTree = signXML(treestring)

File "C:\projects\django\swlicensing\licenses\views\site.py" in signXML
  144.         c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\signxml-1.0.0-py3.5.egg\signxml\__init__.py" in sign
  414.                 key = load_pem_private_key(self.key, password=passphrase, backend=default_backend())

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization.py" in load_pem_private_key
  20.     return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\multibackend.py" in load_pem_private_key
  282.             return b.load_pem_private_key(data, password)

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py" in load_pem_private_key
  1606.             password,

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py" in _load_key
  1784.         mem_bio = self._bytes_to_bio(data)

File "C:\Users\servant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py" in _bytes_to_bio
  1058.         data_char_p = self._ffi.new("char[]", data)

Exception Type: TypeError at /site/245/download-site-license
Exception Value: initializer for ctype 'char[]' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str
```

Is there a way to do this? The code I'm copying from doesn't seem to use a certificate, just using the private key itself.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The `cert` and `key` variables require to be byte array so read it as byte array by the following

```
cert = open(signprivatepath, "rb").read()
key = open(signpublicpath, "rb").read()
```

then you pass it into the `sign` function as you already did

```
signed_root = xmldsig_stuff.sign(
    key=key,
    cert=cert,
    algorithm='rsa-sha1',
    c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'
    )
```